# Click Event for Call Log

Tags: android

I am developing a VOIP app in Android.
The app is registering call logs using [Call Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html).
It is working very well but now I need to make the app running and making outgoing calls when the logged call is tapped.

Is there an API for it in Android?

Comment: You should look at the tutorials on http://developer.android.com about how to place a call.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Phone

Comment: I am looking for a solution to initiate my app from Call Log